# RxJS share memory across node.js instances using Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5

We're working on a project where we are creating an event processor using RxJS. We have a few 'rules', so to speak, where input is provided from a few different source and output has to be generated based on the number of times an input is above a set value (simple rule).

Now, all this works without any problems, but we want to move the project from beta to production. This means running multiple instances of Node.JS with RxJS on top of it.

We're wondering if it's possible for RxJS to share its memory using Redis for example. This way when one of the instances dies for whatever reason, another one can pick up where the dead one stopped. Ensuring that the amount of times the value was above the set value is retained.

This would also allow us to spread the load over multiple instances if the 'rules' get more complex and the amount of data increases.

Is something like this possible with RxJS, or should we build our own administration around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share memory between node.js processes, as far as I know. Doing so would be super-unsafe, since then you're dealing with concurrency problems that can't be mitigated with javascript (what happens when one process interrupts another?)

That said, you *can* pass messages back and forth with redis. Generally, what I do is establish a work queue as a redis queue. Some servers push into the work queue. Some workers will pull from the queue and process data and deal with the results as needed.

A concrete example is generating outbound emails in response to some REST event (new post or whatever). The webapp does a [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) to a known queue. The worker process can use [BRPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) to atomically pull an entry from the work queue and push it into an "in process" queue. Once the mail is sent, it can be removed from the in process queue. If there's a server crash or long timeout, entries in the in process queue can be pushed back into the work queue and re-tried.

But you're not going to get a fancy shared-memory solution here, I don't think at least.